# App Store Review Guidelines Clarification

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

For these 2 rules:

11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected.

Is the applicability of these rules reduced/removed if the enablement/disablement of the features/functionality (11.1) or the content purchase (11.2) does not actually occur within the app on the device.

For example, you write an app that requires free registration but if you visit a website outside of the app (and not linked to from the app) to "upgrade" your registration (by paying money) the app gains some more functionality or content next time you use it.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's a clear violation of 11.2

Comment: @CodaFi how so? If 11.2 stated "...services FOR an app..." instead of "...services IN an app..." I think it would be clear. Im considering not allowing them to purchase/upgrade in any way while "IN" the app or providing any kind of link to the external purchase/upgrade system. Im not trying to rip off apple here. The purchase/upgrade comes with so much extra off-phone/unrelated functionality (most of it) that 30% makes no business sense.

Comment: That guideline literally translates to iApp or no app.  You may think that by linking indirectly to an external website that you can outsmart the review team, but they catch this stuff more often than not.

Comment: I think you are missing the subtleties in the wording of the rules and the important part of my question. The key part of my question is: "does not actually occur within the app in the device",... so no linking, indirect or otherwise. If they had to come to my house for a subscription would I have to give apple 30% :)

Comment: You don't want to know the answer to that question...

Comment: There's another point here that I believe is being missed. This question is completely off topic here. StackOverflow is for programming related questions, and seeing as though we're all programmers and not lawyers we can't really give you good advice on what Apple means with the exact wording of their guidelines. Side note, it doesn't really matter wether anyone disagrees with their ruling on an app. You could bring a whole legal team in on a rejection appeal and you won't be able to get around the fact that Apple reserves the right to reject or approve what ever they want.

Comment: Contact Apple directly with your concerns.  You're not going to pull one over on them, so you might as well get your answer directly from the source.  If you have a solid argument for this specific payment model, they may be receptive to it.  If your application // website has a significant amount of users, you might consider having a lawyer join the call with you to ensure you get the clarification you need on specifics.  Strict guidelines certainly does not mean that Apple will not work with their customers.  It is better for them to have your app, than to not have it.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan Any idea on who would be the best contact point?

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle If there was a better StackOverflow site to move this to, I might be in favor of it also. But ultimately the question might get the best answer from other programmers that have faced the issue directly, and are able to give programming advice to change the app behavior to avoid it becoming an issue. As you pointed out, it's not really even a question for lawyers, as Apple can enforce it however they wish. This makes feedback from other programmers that have dealt with the issue even more invaluable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My thoughts: you'd be violating the guidelines, but your app could get approved, of course. The payment does indeed not occur inside the app, but the application "utilizes" such a system (which is very broad) thus is in violation.

This reminds me of the Newsstand/subscriptions discussions going on before. Basically, if you offer something outside an app, you have to make the same (or better) offer inside the app (via IAP subscriptions). Perhaps this is applicable in your case, too. Although, according to 11.3, you may not offer services outside your app if purchased via IAP (so you may not unlock features on e.g. a website too.)

You'd also try and offer a free app. Once users (somewhere, somehow) upgrade their account, they can access the members only app, a new, separate app. But approval is still questionable, which brings me to my last part:

"We will reject Apps for any content or behavior that we believe is over the line. What line, you ask? Well, as a Supreme Court Justice once said, "I'll know it when I see it". And we think that you will also know it when you cross it."
— https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

In short: submit, pray and find out.

Comment: But isn't what I'm proposing the same as what Dropbox does? You can't find a link anywhere in the Dropbox app to go from a free to a paid account, yet if you go onto their website (or respond to one of their emails about upgrading), you can upgrade your account outside of the app. Then the next time you're in the app, you're taking advantage of the additional space you paid for...

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti Yes, it _might_ be. Although, Dropbox does add disk space, it doesn't add new features or functionality, does it?

Comment: I appreciate your original answer and followup, so I awarded the bounty, even though technically I didn't get what I was looking for -- concrete proof. ;-)  I have another app to throw into the mix... SmugMug. This is an app that requires you to pay SmugMug through their website in order to have an account you can use to login to the app. Without being able to login, the app provides no functionality that I'm aware of. You can get a smugmug trial, but ultimately you have to pay. And they don't use IAP. Thoughts?

Comment: Awarding this as the answer, because in retrospect, it's impossible for anyone to answer this with any level of certainty,.. except the way you answered it,... i.e. submit and pray.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds similar to the situation that resulted in apps that used Dropbox being rejected ([Link](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/05/ios-dropbox-app-kerfuffle-has-ended-but-highlights-confusion-about-guidelines/)). Apple determined that since the apps that used Dropbox functionality required the user to visit the Dropbox site to sign up those apps were in violation of those rules and were thus rejected.

Comment: Except in that case I think the ultimate issue was that you could get to the dropbox website purchasing page via links within the app (albeit inadvertently via the login page). I would be careful about making sure that wasn't possible.